# Pass an argument from a module

Tags: powershell

I need help understanding how to pass on an argument from an imported module.

The module contains some custom arguments such as -one, -two, -three

I am trying to make a GUI using the commands from the module.
eg. If "One" is selected from the drop down menu, pass through the -one command.

However when I do so (using the example below), I get the error: "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-one'."

I can see that using the code below, it adds single quotations around the command which probably breaks it.

I know I can run an IF statement (eg if combobox.text = "one", do this), however I would prefer to use a variable instead of having to make multiple if statements or a loop. The use of a variable seems like a simpler option.

I'm learning this language as I go so I'm not quite there yet with the knowledge :)

Thanks for any help. Hope this made sense.

```bsh
$variable = $comboboxNumbers.Text
#example One is selected from the dropdown

Custom-ADCommand -identity "username" $variable
```

Comment: What you are after are called Switches. I recommend having a search around as it is just a simple `-Option` or `-Option2` type deal, where using that switch will allow you to dictate what the function will do if the switch is "flipped"

Answer (score 0):

Below is simple example method:

```
    function Set-SwitchParams {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
            # Parameter help description
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
            [switch]
            $SwitchA,
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
            [switch]
            $SwitchB
        )

        begin {
        }

        process {
        }

        end {
            if ($SwitchA){
                Write-Host "SwitchA is activated"
            }
            if ($SwitchB){
                Write-Host "SwitchB is activated"
            }
        }
    }
```

Put the method in a `PS1` file, e.g. `SwitchPlayground.ps1`. Then source the file in PowerShell via:

```
  . .\SwitchPlayground.ps1
```

Afterward, you can play around with the command, e.g.:

```
 Set-SwitchParmas -SwitchA
```

I'd suggest studying the following links:

- [about functions basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-6)
- [about functions advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-6)
- [about function parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-6)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

An If statement if probably much nicer, but its possible to create a string and then execute the string in powershell.

As a simple example take this string

`$string = '@("test","hello","whats up")'`

I can then execute it and use it to create an array

`$array = invoke-expression $string`

Which will create an array with "test", "hello" and "whats up" and store it in `$array`

`PS C:\temp> $string = '@("test","hi","what")'
PS C:\temp> $array = Invoke-Expression $string
PS C:\temp> $array
test
hi
what`

Comment: Using `Invoke-Expression` is [highly discouraged](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/AvoidUsingInvokeExpression.md).

Comment: @boxdog Of course its discouraged. It lets a user potentially run any string they can manage to squeeze in to your comboBox. Of course, it will also have legitimate uses.